# How to open image gallery in android 14 (Api 34) to pick image?

Tags: android, android-studio, image-gallery, imagepicker

I have used following code for pick image from gallery. It is working till android 13 (Api 33) but it not working (gallery is not opening) on Android 14 (Api 34).

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        if (photoPickerIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
        }
```

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain **in detail** what "it not working" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare Intent.ACTION_PICK not opening gallery to pick image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used in my project and it works on the latest android. mine has a firebase upload part it may be included in answer so use it as reference to help guide you.

```
 Uri FilePathUri;
 int Image_Request_Code = 7;
 private ActivityResultLauncher<String> imagePickerLauncher;
```

> in onCreate

```
 imagePickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
            result -> {
                if (result != null) {
                    // Handle the selected image
                    FilePathUri = result;
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri);
                        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
 btnBrowse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            imagePickerLauncher.launch("image/*");

        }
    });
```

> outside onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Image_Request_Code && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        FilePathUri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public String GetFileExtension(Uri uri) {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));

}
```

Comment: Thanks @MãĴď it really helps. Just remove the onActivityResult() and handle the call back within new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),

Comment: Happy to help. if there is an edit please do edit my answer